# Would "No way" be a perfectly natural response here to express disbelief?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

**Man:** *Do you know who the hero who saved the old woman's life yesterday was? It was Marty.*

**Woman:** *No way.*

1. Would "No way" be a perfectly natural response here to express disbelief?
2. Also, would it mean she didn't believe him or just that she was surprised?

Comment: [Slang words meaning no, disbelief, doubt](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/thesaurus/words+meaning+no,+disbelief,+doubt+(statements+of).html)

Answer (score 1):

"No way" is perfectly natural for that usage. In this case, the woman is saying that Marty saving the old woman's life sounds like it would be impossible, and therefore doesn't believe the man.

Comment: The _literal_ meaning is that she doesn't believe him, but the expression can be used to mean that you find something very surprising.